# Unable to pass information from local notification in AppDelegate to a view in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, notifications, appdelegate

I have a scheduled notification that works and I am attempting to get information from that notification to open another view, but right now I'm unable to get that information passed into my main view in my `onReceieve` portion of the code.

I can see the information in my AppDelegate portion of the code.

I feel like there's a small step I'm missing somewhere.

tl;dr: trying to pass notification information from AppDelegate to MainView

```swift
@main
struct UntitledNewsApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    @StateObject var notificationData = NotificationData()
    
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
                .environmentObject(notificationData)
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    var notificationData = NotificationData()
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        return true
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        // Handle the received notification and navigate to the desired view
        if response.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier {
            let articleResponse = response.notification.request.content
            
            notificationData.notificationTitle = articleResponse.title
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
                    appDelegate.notificationData.notificationTitle = articleResponse.title
                }
            }
            // Notification tapped, navigate to the desired view
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("NotificationTapped"), object: nil)
        }
        
        completionHandler()
    }
}

class NotificationData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var notificationTitle: String = ""
}

struct MainView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var notificationData: NotificationData
    ...
   var body: some View {
Text("Never Give You Up")
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSNotification.Name("NotificationTapped"))) { notification in
            print("onReceive in blank: \(notificationData.notificationTitle)")
        }

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `NotificationData()` you create a different instance, one does not know about the other.

You can change your injection to connect.

```
.environmentObject(appDelegate.notificationData)
```

You don't need the `@StateObject` the `AppDelegate` will manage lifecycle.