SwiftUI doesn't update when variable is changed in appDelegate
I am trying to have the app check for whether notification access is available, then display ContentView if it is, or NotificationView if it isn't. What I have does this great, when it runs it checks and shows the right view. But, the NotificationView asks the user to allow permissions with a button. I want it so once the permission is granted, then it switches to the other view, but I can't seem to figure out how. I have also tried to do it with a sheet, but same problem.
Here is what I have:
appApp.swift
@main
struct appApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    @State private var notificationStatus: String = "na"
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if appDelegate.notificationStatus == true {
                NotificationView()
            } else {
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
}

appDelegate.swift
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    @Published var notificationStatus: Bool = false
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.getNotificationSettings { settings in
            switch settings.authorizationStatus {
            case .notDetermined:
                self.notificationStatus = false
            case .denied:
                self.notificationStatus = false
            case .authorized:
                self.notificationStatus = true
            case .provisional:
                self.notificationStatus = true
            case .ephemeral:
                self.notificationStatus = false
            @unknown default:
                self.notificationStatus = false
            }
        }
        return true
    }

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks everyone!

Only a child view can observe the app delegate

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76568273/unable-to-pass-information-from-local-notification-in-appdelegate-to-a-view-in-s/76568301#76568301

This question is similar to: Unable to pass information from local notification in AppDelegate to a view in swiftui. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Conform your delegate to ObservableObject, e.g.
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, ObservableObject {

Then keep the @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor in the App but in your View use:
@EnvironmentObject private var appDelegate: MyAppDelegate

Now body will be called when the @Published var notificationStatus is changed.
For more info, see the docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiapplicationdelegateadaptor

If your app delegate conforms to the ObservableObject protocol, as in
the example above, then SwiftUI puts the delegate it creates into the
Environment. You can access the delegate from any scene or view in
your app using the EnvironmentObject property wrapper:
@EnvironmentObject private var appDelegate: MyAppDelegate This enables
you to use the dollar sign ($) prefix to get a binding to published
properties that you declare in the delegate. For more information, see
projectedValue.


I saw that, but that is showing how to access it from the View, I am trying to access it from the App, and since AppDelegate is already defined there, I don't think I'm supposed to define it twice. Any suggestions?

Just make a wrapper View
